# How to set a structure's field to None in const fn new()?

Tags: rust

I am learning [Writing an OS in Rust](https://os.phil-opp.com/allocator-designs/) lessons and have met one problem with structure initialisation:

```
struct ListNode {
    size: usize,
    next: Option<&'static mut ListNode>,
}

impl ListNode {

    const fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        ListNode { size, next: None }
    }

    fn start_addr(&self) -> usize {
        self as *const Self as usize
    }

    fn end_addr(&self) -> usize {
        self.start_addr() + self.size
    }
}
```

The problem that I can't assign `None` to `next` field as it is mutable reference:

```
error[E0723]: mutable references in const fn are unstable
  --> src/allocator/linked_list.rs:14:32
   |
14 |         ListNode { size, next: None }
   |                                ^^^^
   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the next paragraph after the snippet you've pasted:

> The type has a simple constructor function named `new` and methods to calculate the start and end addresses of the represented region. We make the `new` function a const function, which will be required later when constructing a static linked list allocator. Note that any use of mutable references in const functions (including setting the `next` field to `None`) is still unstable. **In order to get it to compile, we need to add `#![feature(const_fn)]` to the beginning of our `lib.rs`.**

Comment: Thank you, I really forgot to add it, I missed it with `#![feature(alloc_layout_extra)]` that I've added before, so was sure I've added.